# What is the fastest way to detect file size is not zero without knowing the file descriptor?

Tags: c, macos, file, filesize

To explain shortly why I need this,
I am currently doing the detection by `stat(2)`. I don't have control over the file descriptor (may get used up by some other thread as my code is getting injected to replace syscalls) , so i can't use `fstat(2)` (which is faster). I need to do this check a lot of times, so is there a faster way to do the same thing? 
I am checking the same file in different processes which do not have a parent child relation.

Comment: I assume this is on Linux, but you should add that to your question for clarity.

Comment: Why must it be fast? Besides: given stat `stat()` is a single systemcall, there is no way to do better.

Comment: Do you have a performance issue, or are you doing some premature optimization?

Comment: do you check size of random files? all files in a directory? repeat checking for the same files? on a local disk or on an nfs disk? I think you need to clarify all those questions.

Comment: @klutt, its on macOS, sorry for not adding that tag before

Comment: @wildplasser, I need to do the size check millions of times, so yes, some optimisations would be good.

Comment: @klutt, my complete project is for optimisation, so yea the more optimisation I do, better it gets.

Comment: @Serge, I will add that to my question, thanks for pointing that out. I am checking the same file in different processes(which do not have a parent child relation).

Comment: What kind of problem involves this?

Comment: @klutt, I am injecting my library into processes, then I create a file and mmap it into each process. For mmap(which makes it much faster than general accesses) I need initial file size and I need to truncate to that size just once, that is when the file size is 0.

Comment: *I need to do this check a lot of times, so is there a faster way to do the same thing?*  That sounds like [a TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use), and [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to boot.  What actual **problem** is continually checking file size supposed to solve?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I belief my question is pretty clear, I just asked the fastest way to check if file size is 0 and that too without use of fd. Further I add some detail of the case in which I need it. I add more points to the comments if anyone asks and I belief explaining the complete project is not the way to ask a question?

Comment: The real question is: what is your program going to *do* based on this information? What should happen if the file has size==0? What will happen if it has size>0? [see also: Andrews TOCTOU-link] Bonus: maybe you could use inotify?

Comment: @Mihir, do you need to know only if the size is zero? the `lseek` approach does need a file descriptor, so it is not applicable also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably benchmark it for yourself.

I've measured

```
//Real-time System-time
272.58 ns(R)    170.11 ns(S)  //lseek
366.44 ns(R)    366.28 ns(S)  //fstat
812.77 ns(R)    711.69 ns(S)  //stat("/etc/profile",&sb)
```

on my Linux laptop. It fluctuates a little between runs but `lseek` is usually a bunch of ns faster than `fstat`, but you also need a fd for it and `open`ing is quite expensive at about 1.6µs, so `stat` is probably the best choice for your case.

---

As [tom-karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5460719/tom-karzes) has noted, `stat` should dependent on the number of directory components in the path. I tried it on a PATH_MAX long "/foo/foo/.../foo" directory and there I'm getting about `80µs`.

Comment: How exactly did you measure?

Comment: @Serge Ran it in a loop many times, diffed times as reported by clock_gettime and getrusage and divided by iteration count.

Comment: I suspect the speed of `stat` is largely determined by the number of directory components in the path, whereas `fstat` would be unaffected by the depth.  Of course, filesystem caching no doubt helps `stat`.

Comment: @TomKarzes :in the case of  {lseek,fstat}, the open() call will allready have done all the directory and filesystem caching.

Comment: @TomKarzes Indeed. I had tested stat on "/etc/profile". Tried again on "foo/foo/foo.../foo" PATH_MAX long (what fit inside 4096B) and I got 79.15 µs.

Comment: @wildplasser In the case of `lseek` and `fstat`, it doesn't even need to know what the path is, since it already has the `inode`.

Comment: yes, but the *dirty work* has already been done by the open() call. (so you should include it in your cost calculation)

Comment: @wildplasser Right, `open` resolves the directory chain so `lseek` and `fstat` don't have to.  I was just pointing out that directory depth affects the cost of `stat` (just as it affects the cost of `open`).

Comment: @wildplasser I do mention the cost of open on a short-path file, but it's still a separate cost. They don't have to be paired. You could fstat/lseek many times for a single call to open. It all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TomKarzes, as the OP says, he cannot get a file descriptor, so `lseek` is unusable in this case.

Comment: @LuisColorado I know.  I was explaining why `stat` is slower.

Comment: @TomKarzes, if you need to `open(2)` the file to get the file descriptor, then you can do the `lseek(2)` but in that case you are in the same scenario as with `stat(2)`.  And there are a lot of race conditions you have to afford either case.

Comment: @LuisColorado Yes, if you compare the time for `stat` to the combined time for `open` and `lseek` or `fstat`, then they're probably comparable.

Comment: @TomKarzes, read my answer.  `lseek(2)` is not viable in a multithreaded environment with a shared file descriptor, while `stat(2)` is, as all the information is got in a single system call, and so it is thread/process safe.  The assumption of not being able to use `stat(2)` because the file descriptor is shared with another thread is wrong, so the solution is to use `stat(2)`.

Comment: but if you have to lseek back to the beginning (or rewind) then lseek and fstat are probably of equivalent latency?

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient approach, knowing the filesystem you are searching in, is to open the block device associated and search (block by block) the inode table, and check the actual size from the inodes there (open the block device, so you get the inodes from the in-memory images, and not from the disk).  This allows you to get all the zero length inodes of a filesystem in a quick and dirty way.  The drawback is that you first need to get the info of the filesystem, and then to access the block device directly, which is normally forbidden for a non-root process.  After that, you have to search the filesystem to get the names of the files involved, just in case you need to do something on those files.

By the way, your assumption of **not being able to use `fstat(2)` on a shared file descriptor with another thread is wrong**, as the stat system call operates on an open file descriptor, and doesn't do anything on the file ---it's nonblocking---, and the system warrants that the inode is locked while accessing the stat structure.

The approach of using `lseek(2)` is not valid in this case, because it actually moves the file pointer to the end of file, and then back to the saved place, and **this requires two system calls to do and undo the move**, and there are many race scenarios that can happen if another thread uses another system call (does a `write(2)`, between the two) while you have the file pointer at another place.

Unix (incl. all posix systems linux, bsd, etc.) warrants that a nonblocking system call (as `stat(2)` is) is atomic in nature, blocking the inode of the file while the process (or thread) is executing the system call.  So no other thread can be using the file while your `stat(2)` system call is getting the data.  Even on blocking calls, unix warrants that a different system call made to the same descriptor will be chained to be executed and the process/thread will have to wait until the `stat(2)` syscall ends.

The problem on `fstat(2)` is that it has to solve all the path elements until it gets to the final inode of the file (this is where the length of the file is stored) and this is done in a one by one basis.  Until it doesn't get to the final inode, no lock is made to the final inode (indeed, it is unknown until we get to it, so we cannot block it until we finish the `namei()` resolving) and then it solves as the original `stat(2)`.

## CONCLUSION

Use `stat(2)` with the *other thread* file descriptor whithout fearing about data corruption, it's not possible to happen.  Don't hesitate to do this, as nothing is going to happen to the inode of the file while you are gathering the `stat` info.